# How can I scale map texture relative to each oriented faces?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, scale

I don't know if the question's title it's clear (if you suggest one more clear I can change it later?).
I wanna use a noise map for making some vertical blurred lines on my wall, so I'm scaling that map using mapping node along X axe, but in this way this is good only on aligned faces (left side of the attached image), on it's perpendicular face wall this is not scaled due to different orientation, so is there a way to get the same effect on that last one without duplicate material and assigned it and scaling the noise texture on the Y axe?
[image]

Comment: so, just to be clear, you want the material one of the walls to be scaled along the x axes, and the other wall to be scaled along the y axis, without using separate materials, is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: Yes! I wanna the same vertical blurred lines on both side wall

Comment: are your walls, the same object, or are they separate objects?  because if they are the same object, then I think I figured out a way to do this.

Comment: same object, inside faces of a cube mesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have the vertical lines using a noise texture on both sides of the wall, this can be done simply with mapping nodes. Simply add a noise texture connected to a color ramp.  then add a texture coordinate node attached to a mapping node.  Scale up the material the same amount on both the x and y axes to get the desired result.  I will show you may node setup:[image]
using this setup, I got this result: [image]
you can adjust the color ramp and other settings as needed

Comment: It was so simple!!! Why I didn't try it!? Maybe bc it's late night? :) I'm so dumb!!!

Comment: @GGKMNTN Hey :). If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted **✓**

Comment: yea, that would be helpful, thanks